# Can a CM choke saturate due to the leakage inductance?

Tags: power-electronics, magnetics

On a 3-phase common-mode choke, if the three currents sum to zero, then it will theoretically never saturate.

I understand that the leakage inductance stores energy in the core.

- Can the three phases have different leakage inductance?
- If so, can that imbalance contribute to core saturation?
  E.g., if phase A has more leakage inductance than B and C, then when current A is at its peak, the energy stored in the core is not zero. Is this true?

Comment: Magnetization inductance stores energy in the core. Leakage inductance effects are usually trivial in comparison and, by there very nature, do not couple (hence are called leakages), hence do not provide CM cancellation effects.

Comment: Do you mean that even if the leakage inductances are similar, the choke can still saturate?

Comment: If leakage inductance is zero the core can still saturate if ampere-turns are not balanced.